# Codeigniter - Fetch data from meta table having multiple duplicates by MaxDate/time using MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch data from three tables.

Table Names

1. table **spa**
2. table **spa_meta**
3. table **Inventory** (Inventory returns only one column unit_no
   using simple join which is not a problem)

The data structure for tables is as follows

table **spa**
[image]

table **Spa_meta**

[image]

- I want to list down the data where basic information should come from
  First table **Spa** (id,title, inventory_id)
- but from the other
  table **spa_meta** only **ONE** entry should be selected with match of spa_id
  which should be DESC according to created_at column(time)

**Question**: How to acheive this using minimal SQL query. As i am trying which is obviously wrong

```
 select *, inventory_id, max(created_at) as MaxDate, inventory.unit_no as unit
from spa_meta t
inner join (
    select spa.id as id, spa.title, spa.inventory_id as inventory_id, 
    from spa

     group by spa.id 
) tm on t.spa_id = tm.id 

left join inventory  on tm.inventory_id = inventory.id
group by unit
 order by MaxDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT spa_1.id as id, spa_1.title, spa_1.inventory_id, inventory.unit_no as unit, 
spa_meta.*
FROM spa_meta
JOIN (
   SELECT spa.*, (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM spa_meta WHERE spa_meta.spa_id = 
   spa.id) as max_date FROM spa 
) AS spa_1 ON spa_1.max_date = spa_meta.created_at AND spa_1.id = spa_meta.spa_id
LEFT JOIN inventory ON spa_1.inventory_id = inventory.id
```

Comment: Thank you, this is leading me to the results. Can we remove duplication from this result which is coming by executing above query. http://prntscr.com/net7f7 Have a look, inventory_id is repeating twice.

Comment: do you have duplicate records in 'inventory' table

Comment: No. There is no duplication in inventory table.

Comment: I guess, this is due to different spa_code field in spa_meta table. Actually each spa_id contains two Spa_code fields. One starts with O and other with C.

Comment: if they are getting same  **created_at** field you have to use a **grouby** clause with **spa_meta.spa_id**

Comment: still problem in the result?

Comment: Yup, i applied group_by. Thanks for the help.